# WCF Windows Service consuming Service embedded in Windows Form

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have a Windows Service with a WCF Library.  On the same machine, I have a Windows Form application with a WCF Service embedded into it.  My problem arises when I try to consume the service in the Form from the Windows Service.

The WCF service in the Form has a "basicHttpBinding" endpoint exposed as well as a "mexHttpBinding".  I am able to test the service in the Form with the 'WCF Test Client' with no problems.

In the Windows Service, I am able to add a Service reference to the Form's service and all is well.  However, when I actually run the Windows Service, and try to consume the WCF Service in the Form, I get this error:

> The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/**IService1**/shutMeDown'
>   cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch
>   at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract
>   mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a
>   binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check
>   that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding
>   (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

See that "IService1" in there?  I'm pretty sure that's the problem.  The Windows Service itself is configured to host a Service called "Service1" as you can see below in the `<services>` section.  So it seems like I must have something wrong in my app.config.

My best guess is that I have something wrong with the way that I have my `<client>` setup in my app.config.  It seems like, for some reason, when I am trying to consume the service in the Form, the Windows Service is using the wrong address.  It's using the address of it's own service, not the address of the Form's service.

Here are the relevant parts of the app.config from my Windows Service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFormControlService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8700/FormControlService"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFormControlService"
        contract="Form_ServiceReference.IFormControlService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFormControlService" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="smMonitor_wcfServiceLibrary.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8800/smMonitorService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="smMonitor_wcfServiceLibrary.IService1">              
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>            
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>              
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

My setup is this.  I have a Windows Service running on a machine.  On the same machine I have a Widows Form.  The Windows Form exposes a service that will allow the Windows Service to interact with it.

Comment: Your service may need to interact with the desktop.. http://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2011/08/13/allowing-a-windows-service-to-interact-with-desktop-without-localsystem/

Comment: ooooh, hadn't considered that.  I assumed that since the Form was exposing the endpoint over HTTP that it would be available to the Windows Service, but you might have a point.  I'll look into it.  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was as follows.  I only had the outgoing `<bindings>` defined.  What I needed to do was to define both the incoming and outgoing bindings like this:

```
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFormControlService" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Since the outgoing bindings were not defined, my Windows Service was looking in the `<basicHttpBinding>` and just using the default one.